# Delay connecting to Network until AFTER router connects? (Win7)

Tags: windows-7, networking, dsl, wifi-configuration

Windows is taking unnecessarily long to start up because Windows (7, 64bit) tries to connect my wireless device to a network before my DSL can actually connect to the Internet.

So what happens is, upon startup, my computer sits and waits for about a minute for the Networking app to time out and report "No Network", at which point my DSL can finally resume connecting to the Internet, and THEN the wireless network is established. {grumble}

Even unpluging my USB WiFi device prior to booting doesn't help.

**Is there any way to DELAY my Wireless Network from trying to establish a connection to the Internet until after my DSL actually establishes a connection to the Internet?**

TIA

Comment: You could try Startup Delayer, it might be able to delay the service. http://www.snapfiles.com/get/startdelay.html

Comment: Startup Delayer seems to work fairly well. Can even delay Services. Problem is knowing which one. But I later discovered the source of my stalled bootups was a failing HDD (died this morning. Removed it and delay vanished.)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/193888) has a method to delay a service until another service has completed. You can also set the service to load last.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking it over now. I'm not sure which Service applies though.